# Counter for completed minions in orchestariton

Tags: salt-stack

Looking at how to make some kind of reporting(counter) of the minions that are completed.
Basicly I'm targeting a nodegroup, with one orchestration which purpose is only to trigger independent orchestration for each minion in the nodegroup however, if you have a big nodegroup +20 or more minions is difficult to track all of them.

Any idea will be appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the returner mysql will help you.

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/returners/all/salt.returners.mysql.html

You can do a mysql query to see the job results.